# Angular 6 com laravel/lumen JSON quebrado

Tags: json, laravel, angular, lumen

Galera estou enviando um post do angular a uma aplicação laravel/lumen, porém meu JSON chega quebrado.

[image: requisição quebrada enviada pelo Angular]

Agora quando envio pelo postman, ela chega desta forma.

[image: requisição correta feita pelo postman]

segue meu código Angular

```
    cadastrar(register: Register): Observable<string>{
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
      };
    console.log(register)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(register))
    return this.http.post<Register>(`${URL_API}/user/create`, register, httpOptions)
    .pipe(map(register => register.USER_FIRST_NAME))
}
```

Código lumen

```
public function store(Request $request, UserService $userService)
{
    // Função para criação e armazenamento de um novo usuário, criando também novas credenciais (chamada para MS-Auth)
    try {
        var_dump($request->all());
        // Validação dos atributos da chamada de acordo com as regras definidas no modelo de User, em 'create'
        $this->validate($request, User::$rules['create'],[]);

        // Enviando para o userService->store() apenas os campos indicados dentro do vetor only([])
        $user = $userService->store($request->only([
            "USER_FIRST_NAME",
            "USER_LAST_NAME",
            "USER_EMAIL",
            "USER_PASSWORD"
        ]));
    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Vc não precisa do stringify, o Angular já faz isso pra vc.

Comment: olá amigo, eu tentei passar JSON.stringify(register), porém obtive o mesmo resultado.